# Stream Linux Console in PHP

Tags: php, stream, console

I need to stream the linux console in a web page.

I need encryption and efficiency. What are the best strategies?

Should I use HTTPS, WebSocket, Google ProtoBuffer, ...?

I'm asking for best strategies because I will hire someone to help me. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has an SSH2 extension that may be of use, check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

I have used it previously to remote into switches.